# Raycast hit game object in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, onmouseover, raycasting, gameobject

I created a 3d main menu in unity, each button is a cube.
I enabled the user to press on the button by raycast hit, the problem is
that I want to change the cube color when the raycast is on the cube and convert it back to the original color when the raycast exit the cube.
I'm using c# and I read about "OnMouseEnter" and "OnMouseExit" - I'm not using a mouse but using game controller  (Razer Hydra).
How can I simulate OnMouseEnter and OnMouseExit in raycast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i understand you want to raycast on the cube and change its color and change it back when the cursor or ray cast is not hitting it, I would suggest using this logic without mouseEnter and mouseExit.

RaycastHit hit;

```
void Update () {

   Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
   if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
      if (hit.collider.tag == "cube"){
        //Change color here
        }

    }else {

    // Change back to prvious color.
```

}
}

Comment: physics.raycast is not a boolean, but a function.